# MPAndroidChart - Linechart - shrink part of the graph with no X values

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linechart, android-graphview, anychart

Is it possible to do something like this:

[image]

? I have in the app LineChart with the time values (seconds) on X axis and temperature on Y axis.

And it's possible that I don't have a data for some bigger time interval (day and more for example) and it will not be very user frinedly if user has to swipe so much back. So I want to create this "shortcut" or somehow "delete" empty part of the graph (with no X values). Is is possible? Maybe there don't have to be this gap but I need to contine from time "10:30" to time "14:20" in one graph without big scrolling.

Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: Or is it possible to do with another graph library? For example https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android or https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView ?

Comment: I hope this will be helpful for you.. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326306/mp-android-chart-how-to-fix-the-number-of-x-axis-values-in-the-line-chart)

Comment: This is a very good chart. Would you mind sharing to code to help fellow developers?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1498) and 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328151/mpandroidchart-with-null-values)

There is a way to get a continued graph and don't have an empty gap in between however the way you are looking for kind of seems like a drag because even though you explicitly dont add the empty data to dataset, it is meant to work like a continued thing. 
Hope this helps, cheers